# Rotate DWM Thumbnails

Tags: wpf, xaml, thumbnails, presentation, dwm

I was successfully able to register a `DWM thumbnail` and [display it in my window](http://www.11011.net/archives/000651.html) (what I mean is the `Vista`/`Win7` feature which allows you to live stream other top-level windows inside yours). Is there any way to rotate the thumbnail in my window? I Use `WPF 3.5 SP1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems [it is currently not possible](http://www.11011.net/archives/000651.html):

> It has basically the same restrictions as hosting Windows Forms: no visual brush, airspace issues, only uniform scale transforms will work correctlly.

Let's just hope Microsoft will add support for more transforms in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Try [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx)

Comment: Of course I already tried that, the problem is it has no effect on the thumbnail. It just stays still.